# lifting state up from child to parent, resets my parents states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

when I lift the state up to a parent it resets all my states in the parent component.

**Parent Component**

```
  const [validName, setValidName] = useState(false);
  const [validAddress, setValidAddress] = useState(false);
  const [validPostal, setValidPostal] = useState(false);
  const [validPhone, setValidPhone] = useState(false);
  const [validEmail, setValidEmail] = useState(false);
  const [validForm, setValidForm] = useState(false);

  const isDisabled = (pWidth, pLength) => {
    console.log("pWidth: " + pWidth);
    console.log("pLength: " + pLength);
    setSheetSize(pWidth, pLength);
    console.log("in isDisabled!");
    console.log(validName);
    console.log(validAddress);
    console.log(validPostal);
    console.log(validPhone);
    console.log(validEmail);
    validateForm();
  };

  const setSheetSize = (width, length) => {
    console.log("setSheetSize width: " + width);
    console.log("setSheetSize length: " + length);
    setLength(length);
    setWidth(width);
  };
  const setRadiusSize = (radius) => {
    setRadius(radius);
  };
  const [selectedOption, setSelectOption] = useState(
    <SheetForm isDisabled={isDisabled} />
  );

 return (
   <Col md={3}>
              <div className="form-check mt-4">
                <input
                  className="form-check-input"
                  type="radio"
                  name="cakeType"
                  id="sheet"
                  value="sheet"
                  checked={checkOption === "sheet"}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    setCheckOption(e.target.value);
                    setSelectOption(<SheetForm isDisabled={isDisabled} />);
                  }}
                />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="sheet">
                  Sheet Cake
                </label>
              </div>
            </Col>
   )
```

**Child Component**

```
import { useState } from "react";

const SheetForm = (props) => {
  const [innerLength, setInnerLength] = useState();
  const [innerWidth, setInnerWidth] = useState();
  let isLengthGood = false;
  let isWidthGood = false;

  function validateSheetSize() {
    if (innerLength >= 30 && innerLength <= 60) {
      document.getElementById("length").classList.add("is-valid");
      document.getElementById("length").classList.remove("is-invalid");
      isLengthGood = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("length").classList.remove("is-valid");
      document.getElementById("length").classList.add("is-invalid");
    }

    if (innerWidth >= 30 && innerWidth <= 45) {
      document.getElementById("width").classList.add("is-valid");
      document.getElementById("width").classList.remove("is-invalid");
      isWidthGood = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("width").classList.remove("is-valid");
      document.getElementById("width").classList.add("is-invalid");
    }

    if (isLengthGood && isWidthGood) {
      console.log("everything good");
      props.isDisabled(innerWidth, innerLength);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div id="sheetOption" className="mt-4">
      <div className="input-group">
        <span className="input-group-text">Sheet Size</span>
        <input
          onBlur={validateSheetSize}
          id="length"
          type="text"
          aria-label="length"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="min 30 max 60"
          name="length"
          min="30"
          max="60"
          required
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInnerLength(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
          L (cm)
        </span>
        <div className="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
        <div className="invalid-feedback">
          Length must be between 30cm and 60cm!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="input-group">
        <span className="input-group-text">Sheet Size</span>
        <input
          onBlur={validateSheetSize}
          id="width"
          type="text"
          aria-label="width"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="min 30 max 45"
          name="width"
          min="30"
          max="45"
          required
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInnerWidth(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
          W (cm)
        </span>
        <div className="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
        <div className="invalid-feedback">
          Width must be between 30cm and 45cm!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SheetForm;
```

I can lift the state back up to the parent and get the correct values, but when I check the states for validName, validAddress, validPostal, etc...
they all come back to the original setState of false.

Comment: can you show how you lift it up?

Comment: Ditto. What do you mean by lift it up?

Comment: Sorry if im using the wrong terminology. I am able to set the length and width in the parent component, by passing the isDisabled function through as a prop, is what I mean by lifting the state back to the parent. Sorry again if im using the wrong terminology. While validName, validAddress, etc... has been set prior to the user entering the child component <SheetForm />